# Регулярное выражение для замены закрывающей кавычки в подстроках

Tags: bash, sed, find, кавычки

В каталоге текстовые файлы содержат вызов функции. Первый параметр - имя файла без расширения:

```
any_function( 'name_file', .... );
```

Задача: к значению первого параметра добавить расширение файла.
Например:

```
any_function( 'name_file.php', .... );
```

Я пользуюсь bash и с простыми заменами справляюсь так:

```
find /dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/что_менять/на_что_менять/g' ;
```

Или использую программу regexxer. Могу в php прогнать файлы.
Но не могу составить регулярное выражение для замены закрывающей кавычки "'" на ".php'" для вызовов этой функции.
Прошу помочь!

Comment: Не совсем понятно что искать? Какие критерии? Или везде именно такие строки `any_function( 'name_file', .... );`? Именно 1 в 1 по символам?

Comment: подстрока  "any_function( '" всегда одинакова: название функции, открывающая скобка, пробел, одинарная кавычка. имена файлов "name_file" всё время разные. затем всегда закрывающая кавычка, запятая, пробел, следующий аргумент функции

Comment: Вот, уже понятнее стало.

Answer (score 1):

В `sed` используется особенная реализация регулярных выражений стандарта POSIX BRE/ERE (например, см. [*Регулярные выражения*](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)).

В вашем случае можно воспользоваться следующим выражением стандарта POSIX BRE:

```bash
sed "s/any_function( *'[^']*/&.php/"
```

См. [пример в Bash](https://ideone.com/uiOVVp):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s="any_function( 'name_file', .... );"
sed "s/any_function( *'[^']*/&.php/" <<< "$s"
# => any_function( 'name_file.php', .... );
```

*Подробности*

- `any_function(` - текст `any_function(` (в POSIX BRE `(` является обчным символом)
- `*` - ноль и более пробелов
- `'` - одинарная кавычка
- `[^']*` - ноль и более символов, отличных от одинарной кавычки.

`&` указывает на текст целого совпадения.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `awk`:

```
cat file
any_function( 'name_file1', '142', 'ssa' );
any_function( 'name_file2', '1ww', 'jsa' );
any_function( 'name_file3', 'faf', 'spa' );

$ awk -F\' 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} {$2=$2".php"; print}' file
any_function( 'name_file1.php', '142', 'ssa' );
any_function( 'name_file2.php', '1ww', 'jsa' );
any_function( 'name_file3.php', 'faf', 'spa' );
```